# Levi-Civita symbol in Euclidean space

Tags: conventions, tensor-calculus

Suppose a component of tensor field is described by $B^k=\varepsilon^{kij} \phi_{ij}$. If we define $B^k$ in an **[Euclidean space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space)** then does the rising or lowering of the indices of the [Levi-Civita symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) change the sign?

I mean does $B^k=\varepsilon^{kij} \phi_{ij}=\varepsilon_{kij} \phi_{ij}$?

Comment: You have $k$ as a free index on the left and as a dummy index on the right, which isn't allowed. You need $B^i$ on the left.

Comment: oh! My mistake.Corrected it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, if you're going to keep proper track of covariant and contravariant components, you *should* lower the index on $B$ and make sure the dummy indices are always of opposite types: $B_k = \varepsilon_{kij} \phi^{ij}$. The reason we can be sloppy in Euclidean space is because of how trivial the metric can be. We can always consider our equations in the basis in which $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$, in which case it's clear there's really no effective difference between upper and lower indices.

About Levi-Civita in general: If we're talking about the *symbol* (which I'll denote with a tilde) we typically define the lower-indexed one with components that are positive for even permutations and negative for odd ones (opposite for left-handed coordinate systems). The upper-indexed one is multiplied by the sign of the determinant of the metric:
$$ \tilde{\varepsilon}^{\mu_1\mu_2\cdots\mu_n} = \mathrm{sgn}(g) \tilde{\varepsilon}_{\mu_1\mu_2\cdots\mu_n}. $$
You can freely raise and lower these indices in Euclidean space, as long as you don't change the handedness of your coordinate system.

Regarding the *tensor*, its components can generally not only change sign but magnitude as well. This is explained in detail in Sean Carroll's *Spacetime and Geometry*, for which there is a free online preprint (see in particular pp. 51-52 of [Chapter 2](http://preposterousuniverse.com/grnotes/grnotes-two.pdf)). The summary of what he says is that the lower-index tensor (without a tilde) is the symbol (again with a tilde) multiplied by the square root of the determinant of the metric:
$$ \varepsilon_{\mu_1\mu_2\cdots\mu_n} = \sqrt{\lvert g \rvert} \tilde{\varepsilon}_{\mu_1\mu_2\cdots\mu_n}. $$
Conversely,
$$ \varepsilon^{\mu_1\mu_2\cdots\mu_n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lvert g \rvert}} \tilde{\varepsilon}^{\mu_1\mu_2\cdots\mu_n}. $$
Again, if you have a metric with determinant $1$, you can raise and lower without worry.

Comment: Could you please explain why should the dummy indices are always of opposite types?Why can't we put them in the same plane?If we define them in a plane in a first place, can we be able to raise and lower them in the same time? I mean if I define $B_k=\varepsilon_{kij}\phi_{ij}$ then is $B^k=\varepsilon^{kij}\phi^{ij}$ correct?

Comment: You could define them at the same level, of course, but I *think*, if the metric isn't trivial, you run the risk of combining honest tensors into something that doesn't transform properly. Upstairs/downstairs Einstein notation, when used properly, is very good at catching errors. As to your question, just remember that you raised *five* indices with the metric, not one. You can switch an upstairs/downstairs pair of dummy indices always, since you will be contracting with $g$ and its inverse, but if they start in the same place, moving them requires two copies of the metric that do not cancel.